# AngularJS controller different styles

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DoubleController" ng-init="content=50">
  <h1>{{double(50)}}</h1>
</div>
```

In the script part there are two styles.

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.double = function (value) {
    return value * 2;
  };
});
```

and

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
```

What is the difference between these two styles and what does `$scope` mean in `['$scope', function($scope){} ]`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See `Dependency Annotation` at [Angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). About the first style you show, it says:

> Careful: If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get
>   renamed and break your app.

So they recommend using the second style, since this won't break when minifying your code.